# How to run a command in a batch file that contains quotes ( "" )?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, escaping

I have a batch file which is attempting to run the following:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN ('git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 54173344ab18a7d8e9ff2614cca62b671c8c7e2a') DO echo %%G
```

Which results in the git error `��fatal: Invalid object name 'format'`.

However if I simply place the command itself in a batch file, I get output I expect.

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 54173344ab18a7d8e9ff2614cca62b671c8c7e2a
```

Produces:

```
Files/MyFiles/header.html
Files/MyFiles/foo.html
```

The issue is something to do with the quotes around `"format:"`.

I've tried escaping them using `""`, to no avail.  I also tried `^`.  I've tried using the `usebackq` parameter.

This loop also works if you take out the `--pretty="format:"` argument, but then I get a bunch of extra text inserted.

Comment: Try using `FOR /F "usebackq tokens=1...` and then use backticks around your `git` command. The backticks are like the single quotes you currently have, but lean the other way.

Comment: You need to escape the `=` character in the command, e.g. `--pretty^="format:"`. Otherwise I think it's OK.

Comment: To see this, I ran a test batch under a debugger (`cdb cmd /c test.cmd`) and set a breakpoint (`bp kernel32!CreateProcessW`) to inspect the command line that spawns the child (2nd x64 parameter: `du @rdx`).

Comment: I found the answer to be as @eryksun explained. Quoting the equal(=) sign resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect the output which should not cause a problem:

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 54173344ab18a7d8e9ff2614cca62b671c8c7e2a >> out.tmp
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN (out.tmp) DO echo %%G
del out.tmp
```

And that should work by redirecting the output to a file called `out.tmp` and then deleting it when you are finished with it.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer is in the comment by [Eryk Sun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryk-sun): the = needs to be escaped. So the command should be:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1" %%G IN ('git show --pretty^="format:" --name-only 54173344ab18a7d8e9ff2614cca62b671c8c7e2a') DO echo %%G
```

and that should work (only difference with original is `^=` instead of `=`).

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell this should be very simple

```
foreach ($f in git show --pretty="format:" --name-only 54173344ab18a7d8e9ff2614cca62b671c8c7e2a) { $f }
```