# Save all commit diffs to txt file with windows cmd

Tags: git, cmd

task is to open Windows cmd in gitlab repository locally and
get all commits from past month and
for each commit find the diff and
save it to .txt file named: date_commitId_diff.txt

So finally I want to have each commit's diff in txt file.

I'm able to get all commits with id:

`git log --author=Piotr --date=short --before={2022-04-30} --after={2022-04-01} --pretty=format:"%h"`

I also know how to print diff for particular commit_id:

`git show 2a62555ff`

but when I try to do FOR loop over commits:

`for /f "delims=" %i in ("'git log --author=Piotr --date=short --before={2022-04-30} --after={2022-04-01} --pretty=format:"%h'") do git show %i`

I get 'More?' question... and don't see solution to progress on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first example uses `pretty=format:"%h"`

But your second uses `--pretty=format:"%h'`: there seems to be a mismatched `"` missing.

I would also avoid the double quotes around the `'git command'`

`for /f "delims=" %i in ('git log --author=Piotr --date=short --before={2022-04-30} --after={2022-04-01} --pretty^=format:"%h"') do git show %i`

Note the `^` in `--pretty^=format:"%h"`.
Without it, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26641138/6309), you would get the error message "`fatal: invalid object name 'format'.`".

To save them (each diff) in their own files:

`for /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %i in ('git log --author=Piotr --date=short --before={2022-04-30} --after={2022-04-01} --pretty^=format:^"%h %ad^"') do (git show %i > %j_%i_diff.txt)`

Note the `tokens=1,2 delims=`  directive, and the new format `--pretty^=format:^"%h %ad^"`.

Comment: Thanks, that works. Saving to file {date}_{commit_id}_diff.txt still missing? Would you be able to help with it as well?

Comment: @PiotrekLeśniak Sure thing. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: What does %j come from in .txt file?

Comment: @PiotrekLeśniak Do you mean you see files created with `%j` in their name? Because in the `for  /f "tokens=1,2 delims= " %i` command, the first token is assigned to `%i`, and the second token to `%j`.